# Is Health Insurance a Requirement for Italy National D Visa Application for UK Citizens

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, italy, insurance

I am from the UK and applying for a national D visa for subordinate work. I have been told a few times that I will need health insurance as part of the visa application.

For instance [this article](https://visaguide.world/europe/italy-visa/long-stay/) which states a requirement for a long stay visa:

> Health insurance of at least €30,000, covering all possible arising medical emergencies.

I understand that an entry requirement is *travel* insurance

from the [Uk Gov entry requirements for Italy](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/italy/entry-requirements)

> show proof of insurance for your trip

But that is not *health* insurance.

I can not find a single mention of health insurance on the [consulate website](https://conslondra.esteri.it/it/servizi-consolari-e-visti/servizi-per-il-cittadino-straniero/visti/) nor [VFS](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/italy/uk/london/#Subordinate-work) nor their [checklist](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/italy/uk/london/pdf/subordinate-work-visa-checklist-2022.pdf). If it is a requirement in the visa application process why is it not listed by the consulate or the firm processing the application?

Comment: Please go into more detail about your **subordinate work**. Is this an UK employer you are doing work for in Italy and are paying you in the UK? If yes, then you must have an health insurance that can be used while working in Italy. If an Italian firm that is paying you in Italy, then that would probably include a health insurance. So further details are needed to answer the question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson It is an Italian firm. Regardless of UK or Italian, the demarcation should be stipulated by the consulate or some other official documentation, no?

Comment: @MarkJohnson let me be more precise in my wording. I’m going to go to VFS to apply for a Visa. I have everything on their [checklist](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/italy/uk/london/pdf/subordinate-work-visa-checklist-2022.pdf). Insurance is not on that checklist. If VFS turn round and ask “where is your insurance” 1. How am I meant to know I need it if it is not on the checklist? 2. If I do need it, what official source stipulates that health insurance is a requirement for the visa application?

Comment: Heavy crossover with https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178652/is-health-insurance-a-requirement-for-italy-national-d-visa-application?noredirect=1#comment451308_178652 but there is some nuance here

Comment: No, it is **your** responsibility to fulfill all conditions for entry. It is for you **to inform them** how you will be insured based on your situation. An employee on assignment requires a **A1 certificate** ([Brexit: new rules for globally mobile employees | RSM UK](https://www.rsmuk.com/ideas-and-insights/global-mobility-em/social-security-and-brexit-new-rules-for-globally-mobile-employees)), where as an employee of an Italian firm will be insured directly. A self employed person (or student) must insure themselfs. etc. Please add the relevent information to your question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson it seems strange that VFS have the capacity to list the requirement for other areas e.g. [the mumbai branch](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/italy/india/mumbai/english/#employment) but it is not listed in the UK. You are correct in that its is **my** responsibility to fulfil all conditions for entry which is why am I seeking clarity on this and why this question exists. I read [that link](https://www.rsmuk.com/ideas-and-insights/global-mobility-em/social-security-and-brexit-new-rules-for-globally-mobile-employees) and I don't see a reference to insurance I'm afraid.

Comment: @MarkJohnson see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer: no, but of course insurance is a good thing to have, it is just not a requirement for the National Visa D application for Italy from the UK. If a document is not listed on the VFS checklist it is not a requirement for an application.

Source: 3 separate VFS agents

#### Update

I rarely see follow-ups of those asking visa questions *after* they have gone through the process.

I have just finished the visa process and can confirm at no point was I asked for my health insurance or any supporting documentation for health insurance.

Comment: The UK Gov page **Healthcare for UK nationals living in Italy** https://www.gov.uk/guidance/healthcare-in-italy says: *You must show proof of healthcare cover:

- before you can register as a resident
- when you apply for a visa

Comment: @Traveller Residence permits (permesso di soggiorno) is a separate issue. You’re correct though, some health coverage is required. Withe respect to a Visa, that UK gov page contradicts what I’ve been told by both the consulate and VFS. Since VFS and the consulate are the ones dealing with the application I’m inclined to take their word

Comment: The sum itsself (€30.000) is from the Visa Code **Article 15 Travel medical insurance**, which is covered by a EHIC (UK: GHIC) card. So this is probably a matter of a false term being used. Since most peaple in the UK are covered by the NHS, the coveraged is assumed and not asked about it (as apposed to countries where  health coverage in not manditory where they would ask about it).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Your comments have transitioned from my info being insufficient, through to the suggestion that _I_ am ignorant and irresponsible by not understanding the rules, providing misinformation by conflating Nation and Health / travel insurance, and finally landing on that I will need a GHIC card and the wording of "health insurance" is a false term. I understand you are trying to help here, but you are really doing more damage than good. Please stop

Comment: Well, I answered a question yesterday about *Travel medical insurance* yesterday and recognised the 30.000 sum today. BTW: have a look at the back side of your NHS card...

Comment: @MarkJohnson NHS Card (GHIC card or even older, EHIC Card) only gives coverage for 90 days and is not valid if you are leaving the UK to reside in another country. On top of that, neither I nor my family were asked for the GHIC card by VFS. Once again, health insurance coverage does not _appear_ to be a requirement outside of the possibility we managed to navigate the entire process due to VFS's incompetence. Given my experience with VFS I would not write that off entirely. I can only go on my own experience, and categorically the answer to the question is ___no___.

Comment: Do you need health insurance for the permesso di soggiorno? Yes, you do, but that is a separate question.